SignalR Websocket AllowedOrigins Wildcard?
Using dotnet core 3.1. In the documentation for SignalR, it is recommended to implement the AllowedOrigins property of WebsocketOptions. We have a multi tenant solution, where its not feasible to add every single subdomain to the AllowedOrigins. I've googled and tried using a wildcard solution like the following examples below, but nothing has worked. So, I'm hoping someone on here has been able to figure something out, or can tell me "It's not possible". Currently I'm hijacking another piece of middleware to do an Origin header check as a fallback.
websocketOptions.AllowedOrigins.Add("https://*.exampledomain.com")
websocketOptions.AllowedOrigins.Add("https://exampledomain.com")
websocketOptions.AllowedOrigins.Add("exampledomain.com")
websocketOptions.AllowedOrigins.Add("http://*.exampledomain.com")


This may also be the reason why

tried using a wildcard solution like the following examples below, but
nothing has worked.

From the signalR documentation requires the following CORS policies:
•   Allow the specific expected origins. Allowing any origin is possible but is not secure or recommended.
•   HTTP methods GET and POST must be allowed.
•   Credentials must be allowed in order for cookie-based sticky sessions to work correctly. They must be enabled even when authentication isn't used.
However in the link we could know if Attempting to use the wildcard with credentials will cause an error.
We could know the reason of this error from  this link:The CORS request was attempted with the credentials flag set, but the server is configured using the wildcard ("*") as the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin, which doesn't allow the use of credentials.
